# Using auto/decltype to deduce array type

Tags: c++11, template-meta-programming

To make a std::pair of a string and a bound function I've managed to do the following

```
auto f1 = std::make_pair(std::wstring(L"send_order"),std::bind(&RESTListener::send_order, this, std::placeholders::_1));
auto f2 = std::make_pair(std::wstring(L"on_cancel_order"), std::bind(&RESTListener::on_cancel_all, this, std::placeholders::_1));
auto connectors = std::array<decltype(f1),2>({ f1,f2 });
```

Is there a way to auto deduce the type of array further so I can type something along the lines of

```
auto connectors = std::array<?????,2>({std::make_pair(std::wstring(L"send_order"),std::bind(&RESTListener::send_order, this, std::placeholders::_1)),std::make_pair(std::wstring(L"on_cancel_order"), std::bind(&RESTListener::on_cancel_all,this, std::placeholders::_1))});
```

Comment: `auto connectors = {make_pair(), make_pair()};` gives you an `std::initializer_list`. Would that help?

Comment: Of course! I didn't think of that far simpler solution. My mind was arrays, but a list is just as good for this.

Comment: Careful with `initializer_list`; it won't extend the lifetime of a bound array if copied

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by @nwp the simpler solution is remember that std::initializer_list is created when doing auto foo = {,}. So a more succinct solution is

```
auto connectors = {std::make_pair(std::wstring(L"send_order"),std::bind(&RESTListener::send_order, this, std::placeholders::_1)),
                   std::make_pair(std::wstring(L"on_cancel_order"), std::bind(&RESTListener::on_cancel_all, this, std::placeholders::_1)) };
```